# WPF tooltip displayed on top of other window?

Tags: wpf, tooltip, hidden

Sometimes (I didn't figure the exact scenario), WPF tooltips are displayed on top of other windows, even when the app window is completely hidden. Clicking on the other window doesn't make it disappear.

Is anyone familiar with this?

Regards,
Yaakov

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've seen this as well.
If you have a wpf tooltip open, and you Alt-Tab to another application, the wpf tooltip stays visible, even though the wpf application itself is not.

You could programmatically close the tooltip when your wpf app is no longer active.